# php replace array value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have following mysql query function:

```
$query_number = 2;
$query        = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER by date desc limit $query_number";  
$results      = mysql_query($query);    

$message['posts']    = $results;
echo json_encode($message); 
exit;
```

I get an array of objects with multiple keys:

```
Array
(
[0] =&gt; stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] =&gt; 4983
        [post_id] =&gt; 56357
        [date] =&gt; 2016-06-04 23:45:28          
    )

[1] =&gt; stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] =&gt; 4982
        [post_id] =&gt; 56241
        [date] =&gt; 2016-06-04 22:58:27           
    )
 )
```

I am sending the whole array to the js via ajax.

However, I want to change the date format to "ago" and send it to js.

I have the "ago" function, but I am not sure how to target the `date` value and put it back to its original place (replacement).

Any help would be much appreciate!

Thanks!

Comment: This question would be much more clear with sample input data and desired output, not to mention the `ago()` function declaration (to present a [mcve]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace value you can use `foreach` and change variable on same address

```
foreach($results as &$row) {
    // Replace date value with ago value
    $row['date'] = ago($row['date']);
}

$message['posts']    = $results;
echo json_encode($message);
```

If you dont want to use `foreach` then you can use `array_walk` function in place of `foreach`:

```
array_walk($results, function(&$row){
    $row['date'] = ago($row['date']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to loop through your result and call the `ago` function:

```
<?php
$query_number = 2;
$query        = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER by date desc limit $query_number";  
$results      = mysql_query($query);    

// Loop through results
foreach($results as $key => $row) {
    // Replace date value with ago value
    $results[$key]['date'] = ago($row['date']);
}

$message['posts']    = $results;
echo json_encode($message); 
exit;
```

I haven't tested it but you have the idea.

Comment: @steveKim are you using `mysql_fetch_object`? In my example it would work with `mysql_fetch_array`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are processing an array of objects -- and objects are modifiable by reference by default -- you can set up `ago()` to modify by reference as well and use `array_walk()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/poo5L))

```
function ago(&$v) {
    $v = date('M Y', strtotime($v)); // do whatever
}

array_walk($array, fn($obj) => ago($obj->date));
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'ID' => 4983,
     'post_id' => 56357,
     'date' => 'Jun 2016',
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'ID' => 4982,
     'post_id' => 56241,
     'date' => 'Jun 2016',
  ),
)
```

Using PHP7.4's arrow function syntax means you dont need to use `use()` to bring `ago()` into `array_walk()`'s callback scope.  Also, `array_walk()` will ignore the return value generated by the arrow.